# Unable to install Vertica 7 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10

I try to instal `Vertica` on my `Ubuntu 14.10`. I first downloaded `.deb` package from the official Vertica [site](http://www.vertica.com/) and then I ran this command:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i vertica_7.0.0-1_amd64.deb
```

The error I get, is this one:

```
dpkg-deb: error: `vertica_7.0.0-1_amd64.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive vertica_7.0.0-1_amd64.deb (--install):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
vertica_7.0.0-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Please do a `file vertica_7.0.0-1_amd64.deb` and edit in the results.

Comment: What results do you mean?

Comment: the results from the command I posted in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dpkg-deb: error: `vertica_7.0.0-1_amd64.deb' is not a debian format archive
```

Regarding the error:

> [Not a Debian format archive](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingInstallationIssues)
>
> This error indicated that the header of
>   the .deb archive is not recognized as a valid debian format.

It means you downloaded something that is not passing the basic validation of being an installer for a debian based system. So either the download was not correct and the file became corrupted during the download or the file they let you download is corrupt to begin with.

Retry the download; if it is still giving this error you need to contact them.